# `rel="nofollow"` showing up in preview but not in output

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering

I'm looking at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/46760/12936); in the markdown and preview you can see a piece of code `rel="noattribute"`, like in the following screenshot.

[image: preview]

It's not showing up in the rendered output.

[image: rendered]

Comment: Ha, fantastic.  I wonder if it's intended to be removed from links only and the code to do so is mistakenly being applied to everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indeed was a bug in our code that strips `rel="nofollow"` from a post's html.

A fix will be pushed in the next build (> rev 2012.5.7.2467).